# How do I break formation

Tags: rome-2-total-war

After pressing CTRL + a number to put several units in a formation, how do I get an individual unit out of that formation again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pressing the G key the unit is immediately ungrouped. In addition this is useful for getting the last unit out of a group.

Comment: Ooh, that's good to know, I wonder if it also works in other strategy games, I'll have to try it out later.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an immediate one click/input way to do this, if there is one, I'd like to know it as well. I always just do it by:

1) Press the number to select the formation

2) SHIFT + click on unit you want to remove

3) CTRL + formation number again